# How to make data service to send one request with credentials instead of two?

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have OData web service with windows authorization.

```
connection = new BaseWCFService.ASUTBEntities(new Uri("pathtoservice"));
connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
string SID = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;
var finduser = (from o in IS.connection.User
                where o.SID == SID
                select o).ToList();
```

This code make two requests instead of one. Firstly, it send simple text/html request, get 401 error, and then send normal atom request with authentication:

[image]

How to make him to make one request with authentication and avoid sending text/html request?

Answer (score 1):

I am just taking a guess but I would say the contructor is connecting to the webservice already.

Maybe something like :

```
new BaseWCFService.ASUTBEntities(new Uri("pathtoservice"), CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);
```

or

```
connection = new BaseWCFService.ASUTBEntities();
connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
connection.Url = new Uri("pathtoservice");
```

But again I am guessing. However As the first request has an Unauthorized, it seems as the contructor is connecting without having the credentials yet. Had a similar custom made function before where I made an override of the function and added the credentials first before doing the base function, it was resolved. (In my case I still needed two requests since I wanted to get the result from the initialization)

Comment: No, webservice allows only one argument there is no other overrides ot its constructor. I think, client try to connect to service without sending credentials to understand that server allows it. But i just don't need it =)

Comment: There might be API's or functions to block an outgoing connection to a certain IP (maybe using a firewall). You could than enable it again afterwards. The question would remain if that would be usefull in or even if it is not overkill.

Comment: Yep, thats why this question is here =) I can't find any API's functions to prevent double request.